# Can Blog Posts be community authored?

Tags: discussion, blog

Some topics such as Certification standards and the like are potentially better written by committee than by a single person. Is this a doable thing?

Answer (score 4):

In a sense, all posts on our community blog will be written by a committee, as every post will be proofread and possibly edited by the editorial team. There is absolutely no reason we can't co-author posts, provided that at least two people are interested in writing the same post, obviously.

Even if you can't get someone interested in splitting a blog post, we can chime in and help in smaller ways. Only thing you have to do is ask for help, in the [blog chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2359/programmers-blog).

There are already synergies forming on some of the post proposals on Trello.

Comment: As a side note, Google Docs is great for posts that multiple people are working on

Comment: @Rachel Excellent point - I might spend some time this week putting together some sort of process for a collaborative article.